# spring data jpa limit pagesize, how to set to maxSize

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have one requirement is to search by pageable and non-pageable,

and in my Java code, I use spring data jpa Pageable class,

```
 Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(
                    queryForm.getPageNumber()- 1, queryForm.getPageSize(),Sort.Direction.ASC,"id");  
Page page = repository.fullTextSearch(queryForm.getText(), pageable);
```

And I don't want to change the return structure,

So when non-pageable situation (search all), how to set the pageSize value to MAX ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In conjunction with Spring MVC you can use `PageableDefaults` annotation with `value = Integer.MAX_VALUE` like

```
public String showUsers(Model model, 
  @PageableDefaults(pageNumber = 0, value = Integer.MAX_VALUE) Pageable pageable) { … }
```

see [PageableDefaults annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableDefaults.html) Javadoc.

In any other client code you can set second constructor parameter to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
new PageRequest(
    queryForm.getPageNumber()- 1, 
    queryForm.getPageSize() == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : queryForm.getPageSize(),
    Sort.Direction.ASC,"id");
```

see [PageRequest constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html). I assume that `queryForm.getPageSize()` is a wrapper type not a primitive. Otherwise you get a zero if pageSize wasn't set by the user (intentionally for a "search all" request).

UPDATE:

Since Spring Data Commons 1.6 you should use `PageableDefault` instead of `PageableDefaults`

```
public String showUsers(Model model, 
    @PageableDefault(page= 2 ,value = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

See [PageableDefault annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.x/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableDefault.html) Javadoc.

Comment: Use PageableDefault instead of PageableDefaults. It has the same functionality, but PageDefaults is deprecated since Spring Data Commons 1.6 (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.x/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableDefaults.html)

Comment: The page size has limit upper bound as the 'maxPageSize' property of the PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver. For this reason if the @PageagleDeafult annotation has a greater value than the 'maxPageSize' the argument resolver will change it to 'maxPageSize'. To run properly needs also  configure the 'maxPageSize' to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 26):

If you use Spring MVC this may help you. According to comments below this answer is fully correct for Spring 4.x.x and maybe ealier, but for Spring 5.x.x you probably need another solution.

The first thing that you have to do is to use `@PageableDefault` annotation and set size to Integer.MAX_VALUE or any other value you want:

```
public SomeResponseObject getSomething(
    @PageableDefault(size = Integer.MAX_VALUE) Pageable page
) {
    return someService.getSomething(page);
}
```

But it is not enough when your size value is very big (bigger than 2000 in Spring Data Core/spring-data-commons `1.12.3`), because size will be still limited by `maxPageSize` variable in `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` class which is set by default to 2000. This was mentioned by [pdorgambide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203628/pdorgambide). You will get something like this:
[image: Response with size limited to 2000 because of default maxPageSize]
As you can see there is size=2000 instead of expected size=2147483647 (size=Integer.MAX_VALUE).
So the second step is to change mentioned `maxPageSize`. We can do it by overriding `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. One of the ways to do it is to create a proper java configuration file in a proper package - if you use such kind of configuration in your project. You can do it also in xml config file if your project uses such. There is my solution (Java Spring Configuration File):

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class PaginationConfiguration extends SpringDataWebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver =
            new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortResolver());

        pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        return pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
    }

}
```

Now everything works as expected:
[image: Response with proper size equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE which is 2147483647]

It is also worth to mention that in `@PageableDefault` annotation `value` is equivalent to `size`. In other words it is alias for `size`. It means that instead of `size=Integer.MAX_VALUE` you can write `value=Integer.MAX_VALUE`. What is more althought it makes no sense you can use both in the same time. If they are different only `size` is taken into consideration.

Comment: @OWADVL is it though? As of Spring 5 there is no default constructor for `org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration`

Comment: @CodeMonkey This answer does not include Spring 5 and I think it is obvious when you look at the answer date. This answer was posted on Jun 22 2017, OWADVL commented it on Jul 23 2017 and first stable version of Spring 5 was released on Sep 28, 2017. So both answer and OWADVL comment were made before first stable release of Spring 5 came out. Now you might find out how to make it work in Spring 5 and post another, better, more complete answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working solution for Spring 5.x.x. You just need to add the default constructor. See the above example :

```
@Configuration
public class PaginationConfiguration extends SpringDataWebConfiguration {

    /**
     * @param context           must not be {@literal null}.
     * @param conversionService must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public PaginationConfiguration(ApplicationContext context,
                                   @Qualifier("mvcConversionService") ObjectFactory<ConversionService> conversionService) {
        super(context, conversionService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver =
                new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortResolver());

        pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        return pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need per-controller limits like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
public ModelAndView users(@PageableLimits(maxSize = 10) Pageable pageable) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/comments")
public ModelAndView comments(@PageableLimits(maxSize = 100) Pageable pageable) {
    ...
}
```

It can be done with custom annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface PageableLimits {
    int maxSize() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int minSize() default 0;
}
```

And extended `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {

            @Override
            public Pageable resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, @Nullable ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                            NativeWebRequest webRequest, @Nullable WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
                Pageable p = super.resolveArgument(methodParameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
                return getLimitsFromAnnotation(p, methodParameter);
            }

            private Pageable getLimitsFromAnnotation(Pageable p, MethodParameter methodParameter) {

                PageableLimits limits = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(PageableLimits.class);

                if (limits == null) return p;

                if (p.getPageSize() > limits.maxSize())
                    return PageRequest.of(p.getPageNumber(), limits.maxSize(), p.getSort());
                else if (p.getPageSize() < limits.minSize())
                    return PageRequest.of(p.getPageNumber(), limits.minSize(), p.getSort());

                return p;
            }
        };

        resolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with `Pageable p = super.resolveArgument(methodParameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);` doesn't take what consumer has sent in request, its taking `Page request [number: 0, size 2000]`, is there any way if we can take what consumer is sending ?

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of spring-data (since v2.0), you can simply create a bean of `org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer` and set `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.setMaxPageSize.`

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer paginationCustomizer() {
        return pageableResolver -> pageableResolver.setMaxPageSize(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be a measure of security, so it can be done globally.

If you are using a Pageable in a @RestController then you can change the maximum with the property:

```
spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=1000000000 # 1 billion
```

If you are using a Pageable in a @RepositoryRestResource then you can change the maximum with the property:

```
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=1000000000 # 1 billion
```

Source https://medium.com/@rafiek/spring-data-pageable-maximum-page-size-1bcc9f5348aa

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Data 2.0 you can also do the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver) {
        pageableResolver.setFallbackPageable(Pageable.unpaged());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

All pageable request use `MyCustomPage` and use a default page and size if not found in request.

If size (number of record exceed the max value) i set a default value, which in this case 50.

```
public class MyCustomPage extends PageRequest{
    Integer MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 50
    //constructor 
    public MyCustomPage(Integer page, Integer size) {
        super(page,(size>MAX_PAGE_SIZE)?MAX_PAGE_SIZE:size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:

```
@Override
@GetMapping("/some")
public ResponseEntity<Page<BaseEntityInformationDTO>> getTemplateInfo(
              @PageableDefault(sort = "displayedName") Pageable pageable, 
              @RequestParam(defaultValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE + "") Integer trueSize) {
    pageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber, Math.max(pageable.getPageSize, trueSize),..)
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my code:

```
public Page<MyObject> retrieveData(@RequestBody CustomParameters query, Pageable pageable, Sort sort) {
    if (pageable == null) {
        return new PageImpl<>(repository.findAll(query.buildSpecification(), sort));
    }
    return repository.findAll(query.buildSpecification(), pageable);
}
```

This has a couple of advantages. If you use this in controllers you can always define a Pageable and a Sort arguments, if the request contains a "page" parameter, a Pageable will be created automatically (if there is a "sort" parameter it will be included in the pageable if it's not null or in the Sort argument if it is).

You can customize the sortResolver and pageableResolver in you configuration and then you have the same behaviour in all your controllers.

This way when you send the request you can specify if you want just a number of records (sendig a "page" parameter, and "size") or if you want them all (not sending those parameters), but you always get the same return structure.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring 5.x.x, set `spring.data.rest.max-page-size=2147483647` in `application.properties`.

Comment: There is a "delete" link, if you are looking for it. But editing your answer to contain garbage text is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=1000
```

use this property in `application.property` and assign a higher value.

Comment: this only works if you are using `spring-data-rest`. If not, I have found `spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size` to work.

Answer (score 0):

The calling application can send the maximum value of integer (something like Integer.MAX_VALUE) to the API directly in page size.

To give maximum value explicitly we can provide below value in size.

```
pageable = PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

You can also provide one variable like `isPageable` in this case, when clients needs full data, they can provide this value to false & you can override the page size based on this flag.

```
// pageable is coming from function
if(!isPageable)
    pageable = PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, pageable.getSort());
```

PageRequest's package **org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest**

Answer (score 0):

Use `pageSize` maximum length is `10`;

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Paging {

    @Range(min = 1, max = 99999999)
    public int page;

    @Range(min = 10, max = 10)
    public int pageSize;

}
```

---

Because when we send page to JPA Pageable object, It has a validation like this;

```java
public final class PageableUtils {
    private PageableUtils() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot instantiate a utility class!");
    }

    public static int getOffsetAsInteger(Pageable pageable) {
        if (pageable.getOffset() > 2147483647L) {
            throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException("Page offset exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647)");
        } else {
            return Math.toIntExact(pageable.getOffset());
        }
    }
}
```

```java
    ...
    public long getOffset() {
        return (long)this.pageNumber * (long)this.pageSize;
    }
    ...
```