# How can I validate size of Pageable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pagination

I'm using [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) with my `@RestController`.

How can I validate or limit the page size?

Without any validation, when clients call with `size` of `10000`. The actual `pageSize` is `2000`.

This could lead wrong signal for last page, I think.

How can I validate it and notify clients about it? Say with `400`?

Comment: Are you sure that you need validation and send feedback to user? you can just cut it to some max value like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44705987/1032167 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/46836539/1032167 and send 400 records instead of 10000. And what kind of client notification do you have in mind? some error response instead of data?

Comment: @varren I'm intending to send 400 for invalid size, because, as I mentioned, sending less number of items could lead clients for last page.

Comment: @varren 400 here referred to the bad request. Not 400 records.

Comment: @JinKwon, I am currently facing that issue. I wanted to throw bad request to the user. Have you achieved it through validation on Pageable? Or you stopped using Pageable and used page and size instead?

Answer (score 7):

You can write a custom annotation to validate `Pageable` object

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = PageableValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PageableConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid pagination";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int maxPerPage() default 100;;
}
```

and Its implementation

```
public class PageableValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<PageableConstraint, Pageable> {

    private int maxPerPage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(PageableConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        maxPerPage=constraintAnnotation.maxPerPage();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Pageable value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value.getPageSize()<=maxPerPage;
    }
}
```

and you can use it over your controller like any other javax validation annotations.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Validated
public class EmployeeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(@PageableConstraint(message = "Invalid page size",maxPerPage = 400) Pageable pageable) {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not good when you've 1000 endpoint having Pagination implemented, we need global solution.

Comment: is it possible to valudate the pagesize to not be negative number

Comment: this works, but what If I want to prevent to pass size or page which do not represent a valid int? Example: /url?page=aaa&size=bbb

Answer (score 1):

Try using Custom Annotations to validate the Pageable object. If it is not working, try the argument resolver as shown below.

You can create Argument Resolver in your Spring Configuration that is extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {

        @Override
        public Pageable resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
            Pageable p = super.resolveArgument(methodParameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
            if (webRequest.getParameter("per_page") != null) {
                int pageSize = Integer.parseInt(webRequest.getParameter("per_page"));
                if (pageSize < 1 || pageSize > 2000) {
                    message = "Invalid page size";
                }
            }
            if (message != null) {
                Set<CustomConstraintViolation> constraintViolations = new HashSet<>();
                constraintViolations.add(new CustomConstraintViolationImpl(message));
                throw new ConstraintViolationException(constraintViolations);
            }
            return new PageRequest(p.getPageNumber(), p.getPageSize());
        }
    };
    resolver.setMaxPageSize(2000);
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
}
```

This resolver will make sure the max page size is 2000 for every request to your controller.

You need to throw a ConstraintViolationException when the size is more than 2000. For that you need to create a custom ConstraintViolation interface and implement it

```
public CustomConstraintViolation implements ConstraintViolation<CustomConstraintViolation> {}

public CustomConstraintViolationImpl implements CustomConstraintViolation {

...

}
```

Comment: The question is how to validate the Pageable object and send bad request (400 http status code) if the user requests beyond the max page size: 2000.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the implementation on how you would validate the pageable object. We are looking on how to add that constraint violation on pageable object.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, in the argument resolver we are adding constraints violation exception based on page input size.

Comment: Thank you, I will let you know once I replace my existing logic with this validation.

Comment: Did you try @Deepak?

Comment: @SunilDabburi - The problem with `ageable p = super.resolveArgument(methodParameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);` doesn't take what consumer has sent in request, its taking `Page request [number: 0, size 2000]`, is there any way if we can take what consumer is sending ?

Comment: @PAA not sure what you meant. Isn’t it what I’m doing in the next line? We get the passed request parameters to find page and page size the user is looking for. If not provided, the default setting is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use configuration

```
spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=400
```

This will not lead to any error if one tries to get 401 records. Only 400 will be returned.
More on stuff that can be configured via spring properties could be found here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html