# Override Pageable max page size at controller level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to change the max page size for an specific mapping but the only way I know to do this is changing the `spring.data.web/rest.max-page-size` on the properties file.

But I need to change it only for an specific endpoint without affecting others.

Is there anyway to override this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer helps me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46836539/8847254)
You need to delete `spring.data.web/rest.max-page-size` property and use `@PageableLimits` with params  in endpoints