# Having a Max Items per page on JHipster even when i ask for more

Tags: angular, spring-boot, pagination, jhipster

this is my first project doing jhipster **(microservice : Spring boot - Angular)** and we have implemented the pagination for most of our `findRequests`.
We have set the `MAX_ITEMS_PER_PAGE` to **20** during the project generation and that's perfect.
But for some reason when i ask for more then `20 items` even when specifying the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` as the page size i still get `20 items max` but if i ask for `10 items` i get the `10 items`.
Is there a way to disable this behaviour ?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751193/spring-data-jpa-limit-pagesize-how-to-set-to-maxsize

Comment: I just read it, it gives more information on how to manage pages but it doesn't give the response to my question. I was asking to get the page size I wanted. But I have found what was the problème, il will post it in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that in `JavaScript` the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` equals to `9007199254740991` while in `java` the max value that an `int` can get is `2 billion minus 1` (i.e. `1 999 999 999`) and it was giving me the `default size` as it couldn't cast the value to `int`.