# Is it needed to limit the max size of entries that getAll request returns when I use Spring Pagination and the database is large

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, http

I need some help. Colleague of mine said that I must not return all the entries in DB, when somebody makes getAll request without page and size specified, because that would cause backend crash after some requests at one time. What do you think, is that true and what are possible solutions?

I've searched for some property in application.yml file and also tried to make Pageable argument not null, but in both cases without success.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using? Can you share some code?

Comment: It's preferable to use default values for page-number, page-size, sort-by in your controller, if not specified use the default value.

Comment: I found answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751193/spring-data-jpa-limit-pagesize-how-to-set-to-maxsize